# System.QueryException: unexpected token: ')'

Tags: unit-test

We have a test class that is throwing below exception:
**Error Message:** System.QueryException: unexpected token: ')' 
                           Stack Trace: Class.ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch.start: line 79, column 1

***More details:***
**Class Name:** ApprovalRequestNotificationBatchTest
**Method Name:** testNotificationBatch

The weird part is, when we validated change set before, it did not throw any error and validation succeeded. We added few more components to the changeset ( on a totally unrelated object) and validated again, and this time it is throwing the error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is a showstopper for deployment: Please let me know if you need more details.  Thank you!

**Line throwing error is:**

```
System.Test.startTest ();
```

***Imp:*** **Same code, the line for line runs in another copy of sandbox with no issues**

**Below is the entire test Class:**

```
@isTest(SeeallData=true)
private class ApprovalRequestNotificationBatchTest
{
    //  static constants declared in alphabetical order
    private static final String PROCESS_NAME = 'Test Process';

    //  static variables declared in alphabetical order
    private static Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest           approvalRequest     = null;
    private static Approval.ProcessResult                  approvalResult      = null;
    private static Attachment                              attachment          = null;
    private static ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch        batch               = null;
    private static String                                  cronId              = null;
    private static CronTrigger                             cronTrigger         = null;
    private static Discount_Approval_Process__c            discountRequest     = null;
    private static Approval_Request_Notification__c        notificationRequest = null;
    private static List <Approval_Request_Notification__c> requests            = null;
    private static TemplateSettings__c                     templateSettings    = null;

    static
    {
        discountRequest = TestingUtility.instantiateDiscountRequest ();

        insert discountRequest;

        System.assertEquals (1, [ select count()
                                    from discount_approval_process__c
                                   where id = : discountRequest.Id
                                ]
                            );

        attachment = TestingUtility.instantiateAttachment (discountRequest.Id);

        insert attachment;

        TestingUtility.createNotificationRequest ( discountRequest.Id
                                                 , UserInfo.getUserId ()
                                                 , 'ABCDEFG'
                                                 );

    }   //  code block common to all test methods

    private static testMethod void testNotificationBatch ()
    {
        TemplateSettings__c templSett = new TemplateSettings__c();
        templSett.ApprovalRequestTemplateId__c = '00XS0000000Mjcy';
        templSett.Letterhead_Url__c = 'https://cs1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015S0000000gHDv';
        templSett.ProcessesToMonitor__c = 'Discount_Promo_TNL_CNH_EMEA;Discount_One_Time_TNL_LA;Tricia_s_Test_Approval_Process';
        templSett.ReplyToEmailAddress__c = 'discountapprovalresponse@x-32qfl8h6p5c04401tvrl9xdez7243sruxu96zohvdm5ueqig8a.s-3kszjma0.cs1.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com';
        templSett.Wizard_Url__c = 'https://cs1.salesforce.com/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id=';

        //insert templSett;

       // Insert an account
       /*Account a = new Account(Name='Test',annualRevenue=100.0);
        insert a;

        User user1 = [SELECT Id, isActive FROM User where isActive = true Limit 1];

        //Create an approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = 
            new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setObjectId(a.id);

        // Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
        req1.setSubmitterId(user1.Id);

        // Submit the approval request for the account
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);*/

        System.Test.startTest ();



        try{
            templateSettings = [ select approvalrequesttemplateid__c
                                  , letterhead_url__c
                                  , processestomonitor__c
                                  , replytoemailaddress__c
                                  , wizard_url__c
                               from templatesettings__c
                           ];
            //System.assertEquals('Discount_Promo_TNL_CNH_EMEA;Discount_One_Time_TNL_LA;Tricia_s_Test_Approval_Process', templateSettings.ProcessesToMonitor__c);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            templateSettings = null;
            System.assertEquals(null, templateSettings);
        }

          batch  = new ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch();
          cronId = System.scheduleBatch (batch, 'Test Batch', 1);

        System.Test.stopTest ();

        cronTrigger = [ select id
                             , nextfiretime
                             , timestriggered
                          from crontrigger
                         where id = : cronId
                      ];

        System.assertEquals (0, cronTrigger.TimesTriggered);

    }   //  testNotificationBatch ()

}
```

***Per Basti's suggestion, I'm adding Apex Class below, in addition to test class I've added already:***

**Line 79 in Apex Class is:** `queryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator(query);`

**Apex Class:**

```
public without sharing class ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch
    implements Database.Batchable <sObject>,  Schedulable
{
    //  private properties declared in alphabetical order
    private Id administratorProfileId
    {
        get
        {
            return [ select id from profile
                      where name = 'System Administrator'
                      limit 1
                   ].Id;

        }

    }   //  administratorProfileId

    private Id orgWideEmailAddressId
    {
        get
        {        
            return [ select id from orgwideemailaddress
                      where displayname = 'Ag Discount Approvals'
                   ].Id;

        }

    }   //  orgWideEmailAddressId

    private String query = 'select actorid'
                         +       ', id'
                         +       ', processinstanceid'
                         +       ', processinstance.targetobjectid'            
                         +   ' from processinstanceworkitem'
                         +  ' where processinstanceid in '
                         + getProcessInstanceIds();

    private Id templateId    
    {
        get
        {
            if ( templateId == null )
                return TemplateSettings__c.getInstance (administratorProfileId).ApprovalRequestTemplateId__c;


            else
                return templateId;

        }

    }   //  templateId

    //  public methods listed in alphabetical order
    public ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch ()
    {

    }   //  constructor

    public Database.Querylocator start ( Database.BatchableContext BC )
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        Database.Querylocator queryLocator = null;

        if ( query != null )
        {
            System.debug('batch query:  ' + query);

            queryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator(query);

        }   //  selection query is not null

        return queryLocator;

    }   //  start ()

    public void execute ( Database.BatchableContext BC , List <sObject> scope )
    {
        //  variables declared in alpohabetical order
        List <ProcessInstanceWorkItem>              instanceItems    = (List <ProcessInstanceWorkItem>) scope;
        Set  <Id>                                   itemIdSet        = new Set  <Id> ();
        Map  <Id, Approval_Request_Notification__c> itemToRequestMap = new Map  <Id, Approval_Request_Notification__c> (); 
        Approval_Request_Notification__c            newRequest       = null;
        List <Approval_Request_Notification__c>     newRequests      = null;
        Approval_Request_Notification__c            request          = null;
        List <Approval_Request_Notification__c>     requests         = new List <Approval_Request_Notification__c> ();
        Set  <Approval_Request_Notification__c>     requestSet       = new Set  <Approval_Request_Notification__c> ();
        List <Messaging.SendEmailResult>            results          = null;
        Discount_Approval_Process__c                testDiscountReq  = null;

        for ( ProcessInstanceWorkItem instanceItem : instanceItems )
            itemIdSet.add (instanceItem.Id);

        if ( System.Test.isRunningTest () )
        {
            requests = [ select discount_request__c
                              , id
                              , processing_status__c
                              , recipient__c
                              , workitem__c
                           from approval_request_notification__c
                          where workitem__c = 'ABCDEFG'
                       ];

        }

        else
        {
            requests = [ select discount_request__c
                              , id
                              , processing_status__c
                              , recipient__c
                              , workitem__c
                           from approval_request_notification__c
                          where workitem__c in : itemIdSet
                       ];

            for ( Approval_Request_Notification__c req : requests )
                itemToRequestMap.put (req.workitem__c, req);

            requests = new List <Approval_Request_Notification__c> ();

            for ( ProcessInstanceWorkItem instanceItem : instanceItems )
            {
                newRequests = new List <Approval_Request_Notification__c> ();

                if ( itemToRequestMap.containsKey (instanceItem.Id) )
                {
                    request = itemToRequestMap.get (instanceItem.Id);

                    if ( request.Processing_Status__c == 'Not Started' )
                        requests.add (request);         

                }

                else
                {
                    newRequest = new Approval_Request_Notification__c
                    (
                        Discount_Request__c = instanceItem.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
                    ,   Recipient__c        = instanceItem.ActorId
                    ,   WorkItem__c         = instanceItem.Id

                    );

                    newRequests.add (newRequest);

                }   //  work item already has a related notification request

                if ( ! newRequests.isEmpty () )
                {
                    insert newRequests;

                    requests.addAll (newRequests);

                }   //  there are new notification requests to insert

            }   //  each step in scope

        }   //  batch invoked during execution of a test method

        if ( ! requests.isEmpty () )
            sendNotificationsWithRequestAttachments (requests);

    }   //  execute batch job 

    public void execute ( SchedulableContext sc )
    {
        //  variables declared in alpohabetical order
        ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch batch     = new ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch ();
        Id                               processId = Database.executeBatch (batch, 10);

    }   //  execute scheuled job

    public void finish ( Database.BatchableContext BC )
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        AsyncApexJob                        job        = null;
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage        message    = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();
        List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages   = new List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();
        List <String>                       recipients = new List <String> ();

        job = [ select createdby.email
                     , id
                     , jobitemsprocessed
                     , numberoferrors
                     , status
                     , totaljobitems
                  from asyncapexjob 
                 where id = : BC.getJobId ()
              ];

        recipients.add (job.CreatedBy.Email);

        message.setPlainTextBody ( 'The batch Apex job processed ' + job.TotalJobItems
                                 + ' batches with ' + job.NumberOfErrors + ' failures and executed'
                                 + ' the following query:  ' + query);
        message.setSubject       ( 'Approval Request Notification Batch '
                                 + 'completed with a status of '
                                 + job.Status + '.');
        message.setToAddresses (recipients);

        messages.add (message);

        Messaging.sendEmail (messages);

    }   //  finish ()

    //  private methods listed in alphabetical order
    private Set <Id> getProcessIdSet ()
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        List <ProcessDefinition> processes        = new List <ProcessDefinition> ();
        Set <Id>                 processIdSet     = new Set <Id> ();
        String                   processIdSetting = TemplateSettings__c.getInstance (administratorProfileId).ProcessesToMonitor__c;
        Set <String>             processSet       = new Set <String> ();

        System.debug('processIdSetting: ' + processIdSetting);

        for ( String process : processIdSetting.split (';') )
            processSet.add (process);

        System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'processSet:  ' + processSet);

        processes = [ select id from processdefinition
                       where developername in : processSet
                    ];

        for ( ProcessDefinition process : processes )
            processIdSet.add (process.Id);

        System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'processIdSet:  ' + processIdSet);

        return processIdSet;

    }   //  getProcessIdSet ()

    //  private methods listed in alphabetical order
    private List <String> getProcessInstanceIds ()
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        List <String>          instanceIds   = new List <String> ();
        Set  <String>          instanceIdSet = new Set  <String> ();
        List <ProcessInstance> instances     = new List <ProcessInstance> ();
        Set  <Id>              processIdSet  = getProcessIdSet ();

        instances = [    select id 
                              , targetobjectid
                           from processinstance
                          where processdefinitionid in : processIdSet
                            and status = 'Pending'
                       order by createddate desc
                    ];

        System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'instances:  ' + instances);

        Integer maxLen = 10;
        if(instances.size() < 10)
            maxLen = instances.size();

        for ( Integer index = 0 ; index < maxLen ; index ++ )
            instanceIdSet.add (String.valueOf (instances [index].Id));

        System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'instanceIdSet:  ' + instanceIdSet);

        for ( String instanceId : instanceIdSet )
            instanceIds.add ('\'' + instanceId + '\'');

        return instanceIds;

    }   //  getProcessInstanceIds ()

    private List <Attachment> getRequestAttachments
    ( Id requestId )
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        String            query              = null;
        List <Attachment> requestAttachments = new List <Attachment> ();

        query = '  select body'
              +        ', contenttype'
              +        ', description'
              +        ', id'
              +        ', name'
              +    ' from attachment'
              +   ' where parentid = \'' + requestId + '\'';

        System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'attachments query:  ' + query);

        requestAttachments = Database.query (query);

        return requestAttachments;

    }   //  getRequestAttachments ()

    private void sendNotificationsWithRequestAttachments
    ( List <Approval_Request_Notification__c> requests )
    {
        //  variables declared in alphabetical order
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment        attachment         = null;
        List <Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments        = null; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage         message            = null; 
        List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>  messages           = null;
        List <Attachment>                    requestAttachments = null;
        List <Messaging.SendEmailResult>     results            = null;  

        for ( Approval_Request_Notification__c request : requests )
            request.Processing_Status__c = 'In Progress';

        update requests;

        for ( Approval_Request_Notification__c request : requests )
        {
            attachments        = new List <Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> (); 
            message            = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage (); 
            requestAttachments = getRequestAttachments (request.Discount_Request__c);

            System.debug (Logginglevel.INFO, 'requestAttachments:  ' + requestAttachments);

            for ( Attachment requestAttachment : requestAttachments )
            {
                attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment ();

                attachment.setBody     (requestAttachment.Body);
                attachment.setFileName (requestAttachment.Name);             

                attachments.add (attachment);

            }   //  each attachment in list

            message.setBccSender             (false);
            message.setFileAttachments       (attachments);
            message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId (orgWideEmailAddressId);
            message.setSaveAsActivity        (false);
            message.setTargetObjectId        (request.Recipient__c);
            message.setTemplateId            (templateId);
            message.setWhatId                (request.Discount_Request__c);
            message.setUseSignature          (false);

            messages = new List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();

            messages.add (message);

            results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

            if ( results [0].isSuccess () )
                request.Processing_Status__c = 'Completed';

            else
            {
                request.Processing_Status__c = 'Failed';
                request.Error_Log__c         = results [0].getErrors () [0].getMessage ();

            }   //  message sent successfully

        }   //  each notification request in list

        update requests;

    }   //  sendNotificationWithRequestAttachments ()

}
```

Comment: please add your code from ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch the error seems to be in line 79

Comment: Line 79 in Test class( ApprovalRequestNotificationBatchTest) is: System.Test.startTest ();

Comment: the error is not in your test class, but in your `ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch` class

Comment: just added the Apex Class ApprovalRequestNotificationBatch to the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get this error is that you are building your dynamic query using **implicit type coercion**.

```
String query = 'SELECT ... WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN ' + new List<String>();
// in concatenating a list to the end of a string       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// you are using implicit type coercion
```

This approach is messy at best, and not really the correct approach. Even if it did work, it is vulnerable to **SOQL Injection**.

With the type coercion itself, you have three scenarios which are all broken:

- Collection is empty
- Collection has fewer than ten elements
- Collection has more than ten elements

These will be covered in greater detail below, but first I would offer some options that work:

- Use bind variables
- Use a static query
- Build the literal collection string

---

Whatever route you choose, your query will be much more straightforward if you introduce **bind variables**. At the very least, this change makes it impossible to use SOQL injection.

If you stick with a dynamic query, you must first introduce a variable to hold the return result, as you cannot bind method results in a dynamic query.

```
List<String> values = myMethod();
String whereClause = 'WHERE FieldName IN :values'
```

If you move to a static query, you can drop the intermediate variable:

```
[SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE FieldName IN :myMethod()]
```

---

I would strongly prefer to **use a static query** here for a couple reasons:

- You will induce compile-time errors if you change a variable name, rather than run-time errors. This change protects your code.
- You can use the returned result directly, with no need to cache an intermediate variable. This change makes your code more elegant or terse, depending on your point of view.

It is a simple enough change to your `start` method:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN :myMethod()
    ]);
}
```

---

I am leery to recommend this approach, but it is possible to **build the literal collection string**. In fact I recommend against it, but it can be done. Be sure you escape your single quotes if you implement this approach because otherwise you are vulnerable to SOQL Injection.

```
List<String> collection = new List<String>();
for (String value : myMethod)
{
    collection.add('\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value) + '\'');
}
String collectionString = '(' + String.join(collection, ',') + ')';
String whereClause = 'WHERE Field IN ' + collectionString;
```

---

If your **collection is empty**, you get the error you list in your post:

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: ')'

Note that trying to run the same query in the Developer Console's Query Editor will fail:

```
SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN ()
```

---

If your **collection contains between one and ten elements**, you will get a different error because the strings are not quote wrapped and hence treated as merge variables:

> System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'abc'

That's because your `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN (abc)
```

---

And if your **collection contains over ten elements**, type coercion bites you in a different way because the output is truncated at ten elements, with an eleventh element added (`'...'`), yielding this error:

> System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found '.'

Because the `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting entire list of scope to list of ProcessInstanceWorkItem at line 79, I would suggest at line 90 do the following:

```
for ( sObject s: scope){
           ProcessInstanceWorkItem  instanceItem =(ProcessInstanceWorkItem)s;
           itemIdSet.add (instanceItem.Id);
}
```

This would definitely resolve the error.

Comment: can you please explain why? please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: @glls Unfortunately, I do not have answer to your question but it helped me to resolve my issue. I would love to know the answer.

Comment: @ salesforcewithfunforce  Tried per your suggestion. It does not throw any error when ran a test in Developer Console( It comes back as a success), but when I run the same test via UI it says (0/1) Test Method Passed.

Comment: @sfdcDev - executing a test from Dev console or UI will have the same outcome unless you did something different in the dev console...

Comment: @Eric: It's exact same code line for line

Comment: @sfdcDev - so you are saying that you click run test in the dev console, select the test and click run, it passes, but running the test from the SF UI it fails.....If so you need to log a bug with SF as they do exactly the same thing and should not have different outcomes unless there is code that is mishandling date/times/timezones etc

Comment: yeah... looks that way....